# nRF24l01+ Outputting Garbage Values

Tags: arduino-mega, nrf24l01+

I just purchased a set of 10 nRF24l01+ modules with a breakout board that looks like this:

[image: nRF24l01+ module]

Note: This is the nRF24l01+ chip, not a clone Si24Ri. Also, I'm using an Arduino Mega.

I'm following the Sparkfun tutorial here:
https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/nrf24l01-transceiver-hookup-guide

The wires are hooked up like so:

- 3.3V → VCC
- GND → GND
- PWM 8 → IRQ
- PWM 9 → CE
- PWM 10 → CSN
- PWM 11 → MOSI
- PWM 12 → MISO
- PWM 13 → SCK

I've verified the two modules are hooked up as they should be. I'm using the *GettingStarted* example program for both units. Whenever I go into the serial monitor when connected to the transmitter, I get garbage values like `<¯�SžRÖ` being output. Whenever I try to transmit a message by entering `t`, nothing gets returned. The same problem is happening on the receiver end.

As for troubleshooting:

- I've wiggled all of the jumper cables to verify a stable connection.
- I've swapped out the modules I was using with others from the package (twice) so the modules probably aren't bad.
- After reading that a capacitor is sometimes needed to provide a smoother voltage to the module, I upped the voltage from the 3.3V the Arduino was providing to a stable 3.5V from an external variable power supply to account for any small voltage dips. I don't have any capacitors available to me at the moment, so I figured this would be the next best option.

Unfortunately, my RF modules are still not correctly transmitting any data, and I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: Check the SPI pins. They are different on a Mega.

Comment: See http://blog.brunodemartino.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/connections.png

Comment: No luck - garbage values are still being output even after changing the wire configuration. I don't see anything in the example sketch I would need to change either.

Comment: Ah, wait! Nevermind, it did work. I just needed to make sure I was on 115200 baud rate in my serial monitor.

Answer (score 0):

Check these things first:

- Is your power supply give a constant 3.3V and a minimum of 0.5A(500mA)?
- Does your code work for others?
- Are you on the right serial baud rate?
- Is the path from the radio to the Arduino as short as possible?
- Are your MISO and MOSI wires twined into each other?

If none of these things help then, please tell me what library you are using. I had a lot of issues with the RF24 library so maybe try using the NRFLite library.